# Python List Comprehension With Random Order

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm creating a list in python and I need to randomize the items in the list.

Currently I have to use two lines for that:

```
  self.documents_news = [(brown.words(fileid), 'news') for fileid in brown.fileids('news')]
  random.shuffle(self.documents_news)
```

I want to have a oneliner and tried this:

`self.documents_news = random.shuffle([(brown.words(fileid), 'news') for fileid in brown.fileids('news')])`

But this is setting the value of `self.documents_news` to `NoN`.

How can I combine the random part with the creation of the list in one line and why is my approach resulting in a `None` value?

Comment: Shoving things onto one line isn't intrinsically good.

Comment: You could use `random.choice`, but why? Are you paying by the line?

Comment: @jonrsharpe in this special case yes  -  it's just for saving space because I need to do this stuff in the constructor and I'm not allowed to write it anywhere else, so I want to safe as much space as possible

Comment: You _could_ do it in one line using `random.sample` if you know the size of the list, but why bother? Doing it in one line doesn't save RAM, and I'm pretty sure that `random.shuffle` is a little more efficient than using `random.sample` to shuffle a whole list (rather than sampling a sublist from it). There are other one-liner options, but they definitely use more RAM temporarily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`random.shuffle()` doesn't return the result, but shuffles in place. You can write a simple function that does both.

```
def shuffle_and_return(x):
  random.shuffle(x)
  return x

self.documents_news = shuffle_and_return([(brown.words(fileid), 'news') for fileid in brown.fileids('news')])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be fine with just two lines. But random.shuffle is returning none because it shuffles in place. So you need to define a function shuffled:

```
def shuffled(l):
    random.shuffle(l)
    return l

documents_news = [(brown.words(fileid), 'news') for fileid in shuffled(brown.fileids('news'))]
```